# How do you make the Skype webcontrol work?

Tags: javascript, skype, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to use this Skype button generator https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol and I'm either rather dumb or something isn't right.

None of the code examples (even with the basic generator) seem to work.

It does load the initial sdk but then fails to load further required resources (seemingly)

The console shows the missing resources.

[image: console]

Clicking on what should be the button does bring up a popup but again nothing happens with it.

[image: missing ui]

```
<span class="skype-button rectangle" data-contact-id="kanyewest" data-text="Imma Contact You">Contact</span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

What's missing?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame ?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen hmmm, yes, but I'm not the one trying to do this. The skype SDK is..

Comment: The ".min" version of the SDK appears to be b0rked at the moment. Works for me without, i.e. `<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.js"></script>`