# skype button doesn't appear

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper

I try to integrate Skype to my web page as described in here: https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol.

None of the examples works (skype button doesn't appear):

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-contact-id="MY_SKYPE_NAME"></div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
 <div 
    class="skype-button bubble" 
    data-bot-id="0aae968e-a971-4153-8606-6c0c8e94b840">
</div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

Even suggestion to remove .min doesn't help ([How do you make the Skype webcontrol work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815947/how-do-you-make-the-skype-webcontrol-work)).

I wonder whether I do something wrong or it doesn't work in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Skype Web Control currently does not work with the last version of the Chrome Browser (version 73) and Edge (version 42).
It works instead with old versions of Chrome Browser (version 67).